# Cake PHP Blog Tutorial Error PostsController Mising

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having a problem with Cake PHP blog tutorial for beginners. I got an error stating I need to create a PostsController.php file, when trying to open the site.com/posts/index page, but I already have the PostsController.php in place.

I am using cake PHP ver 2.3.8

This is the error I get

```
Error: PostsController could not be found.

Error: Create the class PostsController below in file: app\Controller\PostsController.php
```

I've followed the tutorial to the letter, and put the files correctly in the directory.

Here is the PostsController.php file I created.

```
<?
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');



    public function index() {
         $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('post', $post);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the Post.php file (the model)

```
<?
class Post extends AppModel {
}
?>
```

and here is the index.ctp file

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

I've already googled around for the solution and found out that a lot of people is having the same problem, but It's either their solution is not working for my case or they fixed it by themself and didn't post the solution.

Please help me...

UPDATE

the issue has been resolved, it was the `<?php` tag that was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `<?` instead of `<?php` to open your php. You can either use full tag to open php or enable short tags using `php.ini`.

> It's been recommended not to use the short tag "short cut" and instead to use the full  tag combination. With the wide spread use of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. Also short tags may not be supported on the target server

Comment: CakePHP is just php - it doesn't have it's own setting for short open tags. +1 though as it seems likely to be the error (though there is no mention of the file's contents being in the output above the error message).

Comment: I totally agree with you @AD7six. `CakePHP is just PHP - it doesn't have it's own setting for short open tags`. I edited my answer.

Comment: darn it, why haven't I thought of that? I'll try this and post back the results as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the PostController.php file I created.

The name of the controller file is `PostsController.php` - the error occurs because the class isn't found.

Comment: I mistyped the name in the question, the one that I currently uses is PostsController.php

Comment: you need to do this: `Error: Create the class PostsController below in file: app\Controller\PostsController.php` irrespective of what you may think - the file you've created is in the wrong place. If you can see the contents of your Posts controller above the error message - the problem is the use of short-php tags (a bad idea) - replace `<?` with `<?php` to correct.